# Accessing Windows Shared folder using JCIFS

Tags: java, jcifs

I am having an issue connecting to a samba drive from a Java app using JCIFS.  The trouble seems to be the url that JCiFS wants to connect.  I can't enter servername/folder/folder because I do not have access to log into the server to get tot the folder.  What I have is access via Samba to a folder on the server.  I can map it via windows \celery\rim\dev but can't use that in the url to pass to JCIFS.

The url below does not make it to the dev directory .  I can get in if I just do smb://celery/rim/ but that is not the correct directory and I need to move down to the dev directory.

```
String url = "smb://celery/rim/dev/";
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain", "user", "password");
    try {
        SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(url, auth);
 String[] content = dir.list();
        for(String file : content){
            System.out.println(file);
        }
```

Comment: What is your Windows version? Maybe SMB1 is disable in this Windows.
JCIFS is SMB1 only

Answer (score 1):

@Eliad Cohen - I am sure that was the issue.  I solved this by moving to JCIFS-ng.  I just wish they had better documentation.

```
CIFSContext baseCxt = new BaseContext(new PropertyConfiguration(System.getProperties()));
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication creds = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(baseCxt, "am", nasProperties.getUsername(),nasProperties.getPassword());
        CIFSContext ct = baseCxt.withCredentials(creds);
        SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(url, ct);

        SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(dir);
        sfos.write(csv.getBytes());

        sfos.close();
```

Comment: There are some new SMB java project that support SMB2 and above , I think you can give them a try.

jNQ - http://visualitynq.com/products/jnq-java-smb-client (commercial license)
smbj - https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj - (Apache v2 license)